# UiButton state keeps changing when scrolling in UITableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, reuseidentifier

I know there are a few posts abou this but I am still confused why the button i created in a tableview wont keep its state when its selected. When I scroll, unselected buttons get affected and  it changes back and forth. Please help.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [myButton setTitle:@"Like" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        myButton.frame = CGRectMake(14.0, 10.0, 125.0, 25.0);
        myButton.tag =indexPath.row;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myButton];



    }
    else{
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myButton];

    }
 if ([array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row==0]) {
        [myButton setTitle:@"Like" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    else{
        [myButton setTitle:@"Unlike" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    }


    cell.textLabel.text = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}


-(void)tapped:(UIButton *)sender {

    if ([sender.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"Like"]) {
        [sender setTitle:@"Unlike" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[array replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
    }
    else{
        [sender setTitle:@"Like" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }


}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Reusable Cells in uitableview for IOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257378/how-to-use-reusable-cells-in-uitableview-for-ios)

Answer (score 0):

To help you understand why this happens; every time a row's cell is shown on screen on your table view, your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method is called to retrieve the cell that will be shown. That is, when a cell is shown for the first time, this method gets called. Then, if this cell goes of screen, and then comes back on screen again, this method will be called *again*, to setup and retrieve the cell.

So, in your case here, you are showing a cell (which has a button on it) for `Recipe A`. The button is pressed, which changes it's state. When `Recipe A` goes off screen, and then comes back on screen, you get back a different cell (because of table cell re-use with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`). For the button on that cell, two things are going on:

- There is already a button on the cell from the first time it was used (maybe for a different recipe). You don't tell it whether it should be in the 'liked' or 'unliked' state for `Recipe A`.
- You add another button to the cell, but you don't actually set its frame/title, so you won't actually see it any way.

What you need to do is keep a track, in your model somewhere, of which of your items (recipes) the user has 'liked'. You'd do this somewhere in your `tapped:` method.

Then, in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, you need to set the button to the appropriate state ('liked' or not) for that row/recipe.

You need to make sure you do this every time the method is called, not just in your `if (cell == nil)` block. By the way, is there a reason you are using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` instead of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:indexPath`? The latter is available from iOS 6 onwards, and is guaranteed to return a cell, so you don't need to do this `if (cell == nil)` business.

Comment: thanks for your response. I added a mutable array of 1 and 0 to keep track of the data but am still running to the same issue ` 
`if ([array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row==0]) {
        [myButton setTitle:@"Like" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    else{
        [myButton setTitle:@"Unlike" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}  `not sure what you mean by dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:indexPath?`I tried but got an error

Comment: the above edits are updated in the original post. I also added `[array replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
` to update the array when button is tapped. Still same issue though

Comment: Where you are looking up the value in your `array`, it needs to be `if ([array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == 0)`. You might want to consider creating a `Recipe` class instead though, to encapsulate everything about a recipe (it could have a name/title, and a 'liked' property).

Comment: You are also setting the button title on the button that you are not setting a frame for. I'd advise you to create your own `UITableViewCell` subclass (preferably with a `xib`). It'll make this a bit easier for you.

Comment: What's your deployment target (iOS version) for your project?