# Xcode adding new TableView cell adds new cell but shows deleted cell's textfield

Tags: uitableview, cell, textfield, reuseidentifier

I have a tableview that displays cells. Some of these cells have to be removed with a toggle button and then some are added in.

So I have 4 cells in my 3rd section. Their titles in ascending order are follows: same?, start, end, duration. The second and third cells in my list have text fields as `accesoryViews` and these both get deleted when the toggle button (in the top cell) is turned off. So this leaves me with 2 cells: same? and duration in my 3rd section.

If I press a button it adds in 2 cells to the same section (section 3) but for some reason they have the text fields from the 2 cells that have been deleted as their accessory views.

My code is as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"creatures"];
    if (nil == cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:@"creatures"];
    }
    switch (indexPath.section)
    {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:

            break;
        case 2:

            cell.textLabel.text = [timesTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

            if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                sameTimeEverydaySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
                [sameTimeEverydaySwitch setOn:YES];
                [sameTimeEverydaySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(sameEverydaySwitchChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
                cell.accessoryView = sameTimeEverydaySwitch;
            }
            if ([[timesTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Start time:"]) {

                cell.accessoryView = startTimeTextfield;
                NSLog(@"log");
            }

            if ([[timesTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"End time:"]) {

                cell.accessoryView = endTimeTextfield;
                NSLog(@"log2");

            }

            if ([[timesTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Meeting duration"]) {

                cell.accessoryView = meetingDurationTextfield;

            }

            break;
        default:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Not Found";
    }
    return cell;
}
```

When the button is toggled, I call:

```
if (![sameTimeEverydaySwitch isOn]) {

    for (int j = 0; j < timesTitles.count; j++) {
        if ([[timesTitles objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToString:@"Start time:"]) {
            [timesTitles removeObjectAtIndex:j];
        }
        if ([[timesTitles objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToString:@"End time:"]) {
            [timesTitles removeObjectAtIndex:j];
        }
    }
        [timesTitles addObjectsFromArray:daysToAddToTitlesArray];


    NSArray *deleteIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:2],
                                 [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:2],
                                 nil];
    NSMutableArray *insertIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 2; i < [timesTitles count]; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:2];
        [insertIndexPaths addObject:path];
    }

    UITableView *tv = (UITableView *)self.view;

    [tv beginUpdates];
    [tv insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [tv endUpdates];

}
```

This code successfully deletes the 2 middle cells.

When I go to add 2 new cells below the remaining 2 using:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < daysToAddToTitlesArray.count; i++) {

        if (![timesTitles containsObject:[daysToAddToTitlesArray objectAtIndex:i]]) {

            NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[timesTitles count] inSection:2];
            [timesTitles insertObject:[daysToAddToTitlesArray objectAtIndex:i] atIndex:[timesTitles count]];
            [insertIndexPaths addObject:path];

        }
    }
    UITableView *tv = (UITableView *)self.view;
    [tv beginUpdates];
    [tv insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    [tv endUpdates];
```

It successfully adds the 2 new cells below but they bot have text fields in them.

The only output for when I run the app is: log and log2.

I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are familiar with reusable cell concept. (if you are not pleas check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257378/how-to-use-reusable-cells-in-uitableview-for-ios/25258604#25258604))

In your code I can see that `cell.accessoryView` are set only if one of the criteria is true, otherwise it take accessory from reusable cell.

Check titles inside array and index (use debug mode)

Marko

Comment: Hey. Thank you very much for your comment. I eventually got it by adding an else statement containing "cell.accessoryView = nil" wherever I don't want an accessoryView.

Comment: Glad I could help :D If you are happy with my answer you could up vote it :D